# What's wrong with this code?

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I wrote this code:

```
public class FileViewer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

JFileChooser chooser;

FileNameExtensionFilter filter = null;

JEditorPane pane = null;

JTextField text = null;

JButton button;

JTextArea o = null;

URL url;

public FileViewer(JTextArea o) {
    this.o = o;
    setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
    JTextField text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
    text.setColumns(45);
    text.revalidate();
    text.setEditable(true);

    button = new JButton("Browse");
    add(text);
    add(button);
    filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("html", "html");
    chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

    button.addActionListener(this);

}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    Graphics2D graphic = (Graphics2D) g;
    graphic.drawString("HTML File:", 10, 20);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    int returnVal = 0;
    if (event.getSource() == button) {
        returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(FileViewer.this);
        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            text.setToolTipText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());

        } else
            o.append("Open command cancled by user.");
      }
     }
}
```

But in the line: `text.setToolTipText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());` a NullPointerException is thrown!

**EDIT**
I have fixed the problem which I have mentioned above but it doesn't work correctly (it doesn't write the name of the file in the text!) :-(

Comment: Well, your 'text' member variable is initialized to null in the code shown

Comment: I have fixed the problem which I have mentioned above but it doesn't work correctly(it doesn't write the name of the file in the text!!!) :-(

Comment: Spellchecking police, btw: it's "canceled" or "cancelled" depending on whether you're using US or British English, not "cancled".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your other point:

```
text.setToolTipText(chooser.getSelectedFile().getName());
```

Was this the intended behaviour? The filename will only appear as a tooltip when you mouse over the text field. To put text directly into a JTextField you should call `setText()` instead.

Answer (score 13):

You've declared `text` globally and assigned `NULL` to it. In your constructor for `FileViewer` you declare it again with `new`, but this declaration is local. The variable referenced in `actionPerformed()` is the global one, which is still `NULL`, so you get the exception. If you change

```
JTextField text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
```

to

```
text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
```

that should fix it.

Comment: yes ,it has been fixed! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

replace this:

```
JTextField text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
```

with this:

```
text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
```

Answer (score 2):

The field text is null as in your FileViewer constructor you have created a local variable called text that has been added to the form.

Replace

```
JTextField text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
```

with

```
text = new JTextField("file...", 31);
```

Answer (score 1):

`setToolTipText` method does not set the text. It sets the tooltip text, which is shown when mouse hovers the text. Use `setText` method.